# How to add a checkbox with categories of entries to the form Contact Form 7 Wordpress

Tags: forms, plugin-contact-form-7

How to display categories in the form along with subcategories that will expand only after clicking on the categories, Do you have any ideas for this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about

> subcategories that will expand only after clicking

I have never seen any form fields that does this.

However, you can use the dynamic_dropdonw field available in the [Smart Grid-Layout Extension for CF7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) plugin.   It allows you to build a [select2](https://select2.org/) droddown field using a category.  Select2 js are quite cool with automatic listing of options when you type.  Try it out and see if this helps.

Answer (score -1):

To have a select box inside of Contact Form 7 you can use the [select] option.

https://contactform7.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus/

Here is an example:

```
[select your-country "China" "India" "San Marino"]
```

Comment: But I need to add an entry category id